# Yii2 : How to update only Font Awesome library using composer?

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I have update only latest Font Awesome library using composer without update other packages in yii2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1st. Require version of library which you need to update:

```
php composer.phar require cinghie/yii2-fontawesome "2.1"
```

2nd. Update it via composer:

```
composer.phar update cinghie/yii2-fontawesome
```

Or you can just do 2nd if don't need specific version to update single library.

Comment: without `cinghie` is it posible?

Comment: `cinghie/yii2-fontawesome` just for example. Use name of your library for font awesome from `composer.json`

Comment: My fontawesome library is default its provided by yii2, My fontawesome vendor path is `@app/vendor/bower/fontawesome/` and my `composer.json` i have not found in any `fontawesome` library name.

Comment: then its bower dependency not composer.

Comment: I think `bower update name` should work. Otherwise read documentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101563/discussion-between-hiren-bhut-and-ineersa).

Answer (score 0):

Odd question.

Because there is no FontAwesome installed with Yii 2 .. :)

However, if you want to install it, or update it, then you should use this package name:

```
bower-asset/fontawesome
```

You could also install a Yii 2 extension that gives you an asset bundle with fontawesome:
https://packagist.org/packages/rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome

I am curious:
What package are you using that requires fontawesome?
And why do you want to update the fontawesome package?